# Automorphic forms on $GL(3)$

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms

It is well known and mentioned/proved in most introductory texts that the only automorphic forms on lower general groups are (constant functions and other details aside):

$GL(1)$: Hecke characters

$GL(2)$: modular forms and Maass forms

Then they usually consider $GL(n)$ directly.

My question is:

> - What are the automorphic forms in $GL(3)$?

I am aware of this other question on MO: [Automorphic forms on GL(3)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43377/automorphic-forms-on-gl3), which deals with a related issue. In particular, a partial answer seems to be given:

$GL(3)$: Maass forms and Gelbart-Jacquet lifts.

Comment: I don't know what you're looking for in an answer. Read Goldfeld's book, where he has a couple of chapters on automorphic forms on $\mathrm{GL}(3)$. He gives a definition of such automorphic forms, and there's really no better answer than that. They're not as easily described as automorphic forms on $\mathrm{GL}(2)$, but there's no simpler description.